# "Однозначные элементы" в множестве/коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

> Интерфейс `Set` расширяет интерфейс `Collection` для управления множествами, которые должны содержать **однозначные элементы**.

Что значат **однозначные элементы**?

Comment: Откуда эта цитата?

Comment: [стр 567](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Однозначные элементы*  - неудачный перевод. Тут имеется ввиду, *уникальные элементы*.

Но, чтобы элементы считались уникальные, при использовании `java.util.HashSet` следует корректно переопределить методы `java.lang.Object.equals` и `java.lang.Object.hashCode`. Т.е. между ними должен выполняться контракт:

1. Если для двух элементов метод `equals` возвращает **true**, то функция `hashCode` для этих двух объектов имеет одинаковое значение.
2. Если `hashCode` для двух элементов имеет одинаковое значение, это совсем не значит, что `equals` будет возвращать для них **true**. Т.к. возможны *коллизии*.

Например, если мы напишем следующий код:

```
Element e1 = new Element("hello");
Element e2 = new Element("world");
Element e3 = new Element("hello");

Set<Element> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(e1, e2, e3));

System.out.println(set);
```

И хотим, чтобы он выводил, только элементы с разными значениями:

> [world, hello]

Нам нужно определить класс таким образом:

```
public static class Element {
    private final String value;

    public Element(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return value.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Element)
            return Objects.equals(((Element) o).value, this.value);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Дабы можно было избавиться от "возможно имелось в виду" в ответе, приведу оригинал: _"The Set interface defines a set. It extends Collection and specifies the behavior of a collection that does not allow duplicate elements"_

Comment: @Regent спасибо, за комментарий.